# Are pointers and inout in Swift supposed to work this way?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am working on Swift Xcode 6.2 and am having trouble understanding the way Swift pointers work.

So I have two classes, wherein I have functions calling each other. I want to pass a dictionary from Class A to Class B, make some changes to the dictionary in Class B and then callback a function from Class A.

Let's say we have some dummy code as follows:

```
Class A {
    var airports: [String: String] = ["YYZ": "Toronto Pearson", "DUB": "Dublin"]

    func foo() {
        B.bar(&airports);
    }

    func foo2() {
        println(airports["CCU"]);
    }
}
```

Different file:

```
class B {
    func bar(inout dict : [String: String]) {
        dict["CCU"] = "Kolkata";
        A.foo2();
    }
}
```

According to the flow of commands, the above should print "Kolkata", however there is a nil value obtained in that case.

Does this mean Swift follows Copy on Write and parses the pointer back after the entire function has been executed? If yes, what is the best way around it, writing a wrapper class for the dictionary?

Comment: This code should have given compiler errors, as you are trying to call a member function of class B, without initialising an instance of B in your class A.

Answer (score 0):

declare an instance variable of class B in class A and then use 'bar' method of Class B in Class A . Same Way declare an Instance variable of CLass A in Class B and then start using it . else make all three functions as class functions by this format  class func foo() {...}

Answer (score 0):

The technique you are using is pass by reference and is the correct way for modifying a variable's value by passing reference to it to another function.

Slightly modifying your code, you can see it working.

```
class A {
    var airports: [String: String] = ["YYZ": "Toronto Pearson", "DUB": "Dublin"]

    func foo() {
        B().bar(&airports);
        foo2()
    }

    func foo2() {
        print(airports["CCU"]);
    }
}


class B {
    func bar(inout dict : [String: String]) {
        dict["CCU"] = "Kolkata";

    }
}



A().foo()
```